# Как удалить приложение не трогая сервис

Tags: android

После запуска приложения активити стартует сервис, как после этого удалить приложение не трогая сервис?

Comment: Что значит удалить? Удалить аппу или убить запущенное приложение?

Comment: Удалить аппу запустившую сервис, оставив работать только сервис

Answer (score 1):

просто сделать finish()?

Comment: @script_kid вы понимаете, что спрашиваете?

Comment: можно будет, если нужно. Не нужно - не запускайте. Всех делов то.

Comment: Понимаю! удалить нужно принудительно! чтобы нельзя было запустить второй раз! И сделать это нужно программно, если можно!

Comment: наверно рутировать девайс надо будет.. так прав не хватит

Comment: тогда можно через Preferences задать чтобы не стартовал активити второй раз, только нужно ярлык удалить. Это реально? Как?

Answer (score 0):

Удалить - никак. 
А если просто остановить то использовать Remote Service